# Error in the opening of a new push notification channel

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

My application used to work just fine, but yesterday starts to give me an error when I try to open a push notification channel via Google Drive .NET SDK, the error is:

```
Failed to create channel [400]

Message[Failed to create channel] 
Location[ - ] 
Reason[invalidArgument] 
Domain[global]
```

You can see my code here:

```
public async Task<Channel> StartWebHookWatch(TokenResponse token, string userId, string channelId, string pageToken, string urlCallBack)
{
    var service = GetDriveService(token);
    var expireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(604800); // 1 Week

     var channel = new Channel()
     {
       Id = channelId, // Just a Guid created with "Guid.NewGuid().ToString();"
       Token = userId, // Just a Id to bind the channel With My appUser
       Type = "web_hook",
       Address = urlCallBack, // Authorized Url
       Expiration = (long)expireDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalMilliseconds
     };

     return await service.Changes.Watch(channel, pageToken).ExecuteAsync();
}

private DriveService GetDriveService(TokenResponse token)
    {
        return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = new UserCredential(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer() { ClientSecrets = ClientSecret }),
                ClientSecret.ClientId, token),
            ApplicationName = AppName
        });
    }
```

I just did a lot of tests and I don't find even a clue what is the problem... 
I appreciate some help to solve this, Thank you, guys.

Comment: Can you check if you're still authenticated? Maybe you're tokens has expired.

Comment: I refreshed the token before open a channel and the error persists...